# Page load time increased 7 times after Debian update 6 to 7

Tags: debian, performance, debian-wheezy, munin, upgrade

I updated Debian 6 to 7. After update `HTTP page load time` graph (Munin) increased from 0.1 to 0.7 seconds.

What could be the problem? What could break and need to check?

Thanks!

[Munin - HTTP load time of a page graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOBuI.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should do a more in-depth analysis of the load time using a more detailed tool (like the Network tab of the Chrome Developer Tools [F12]). This will show you exactly what the time is spent on and help you pinpoint the problem.

Also, I would do a complete difference of the Apache (assuming that is what you are using since you did not specify) configs so that you can pinpoint any configuration differences.

A possible explanation that I would first look into would be that (since the Munin script uses `wget -p`) on Debian 6 you had http keep alive enabled and now it's disabled so it takes more time to make the connections.

My guess is that it's an HTTP server or client configuration difference, otherwise it wouldn't explain such a big gap.